# "From by" vs "by"?

Tags: prepositions

I came across a clause while reading a definition of "swindle" in M-W dictionaries which was:

to take money or property from by fraud or deceit

What if fraud was preceded by just "by" and what difference would it have made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better understanding, this could be rephrased, or rather, re-written as:

> "to take money or property from (*someone*), by fraud or deceit"